# Do while nested Loop

Tags: excel, vba

A simple table with four columns, `column 1` which has data is called `_Log Hour`, `column 2` which has data, is called `Calls`. `Columns 3` and `4 _Hour logged` and `_Sum Calls` per Hour are currently empty waiting to be populated.

```
_Log Hour   Calls   _HourLogged _Sum Calls per Hour
8             3     
9             2     
9             4     
9             7     
9             2     
10            2     
10            2     
10            4
```

I've tried that basic of Do while

```
Sub automate()
    r = 2
    Do While Cells(r, 1) <> ""
    Cells(r, 3) = Cells(r, 1) * Cells(r, 2)
    r = r + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Just to try and see how it works, that is a success but What it should take the first `_LogHour`, enter it in `_Hourlogged` then whilst the `_LogHour` doesn't change I want it sum Calls.

So, for instance, an updated table would look something like this

```
_Log Hour   Calls   _HourLogged _Sum Calls per Hour
8             3         8                 3
9             2         9                15
9             4     
9             7     
9             2     
10            2         10                8
10            2     
10            4
```

Comment: Why not use formulae? SUMIF would do most of this for you.

Comment: … or use a pivot table

Answer (score 1):

This would be a pattern you can use for this type of summary:

```
Sub automate()

    Const ROW_START As Long = 2
    Const COL_HR As Long = 1
    Const COL_CALLS As Long = 2
    Const COL_HR_SUMM As Long = 3
    Const COL_CALLS_SUMM As Long = 4

    Dim r As Long, rw As Range, currentHr, hr, rwHr As Long, sht As Worksheet

    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    r = ROW_START

    Do While sht.Cells(r, COL_HR).Value <> ""
        hr = sht.Cells(r, COL_HR).Value
        If r = ROW_START Or hr <> currentHr Then '<< at start, or a new hour value?
            rwHr = r                             '<< store the row we first saw this hour
            currentHr = hr                       '<< store the hour
            sht.Cells(rwHr, COL_HR_SUMM).Value = currentHr
            sht.Cells(rwHr, COL_CALLS_SUMM).Value = Cells(r, COL_CALLS).Value
        Else
            'not a new hour, so update the previously-saved row
            With sht.Cells(rwHr, COL_CALLS_SUMM)
                .Value = .Value + sht.Cells(r, COL_CALLS).Value
            End With
        End If

        r = r + 1

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Tim - that works a treat and better still your commentary makes it clear to understand what it is doing, thanks very much